# Row based Access control for Laravel Results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'd like to setup a row based access control on my laravel application (currently 5.2, waiting for 5.5 lts). This could be done in the controller, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it a bit deeper in the framework.

Let's say there are these models:

```
P - project
U - user (assigned to many projects)
D - Device (assigned to one project)
F - FAQ document (assigned to one project)
```

The currently logged in user should only see those devices and faq documents that belong to their projects.

My current attempt is to do this in the controller. Get the current user, check for a generic "access all project" permission and - if not present - join the project for the asked model to limit the result. This has to be replicated on all queries that are running for this model and I am feeling that this kind of redundancy is not perfect.

Is there a way to create something like a interface trait with a method `withAccess()` that forces those models (Device and FAQ Document in my example) to implement this method and do the query once on the model definition?

Comment: I would like to prefer creating middleware (system wide middleware that works as filter). Actually I did not understand what do you mean by row based access control.

Comment: As I understood currenlty, the middleware acts well for filtering a request in case of no access at all, like if you want to access a device that does not belong to one of your projects. But what if you want to access a list of devices? How could a middleware be usefull here? (e.g. filtering the result set)

Comment: no you can do anything using that middleware, on success you can pass your list of devices to the next request and get that in your controller or view (on next page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I can think off is to use a reusable scope for each model.

e.g.

In your controller:

```
$devices = Device::ViewableDevices()->get();
```

and in your `Device` model:

```
public function scopeViewableDevices($query)
{

    return $query->whereHas('project', function($query) {
        $query->whereHas('user', function($query) {
            $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
        }
    });

}
```

The query might be wrong compared to how your data is stored and the logic you are trying to achieve but what I am meaning in the scope is to find the project for the device, then find the user for the project and see if it belongs to the logged in user.

For this to work you'd need to setup a `project` relationship in the `Device` model and a `user` relationship in the `Project` model.

e.g.

```
// Device.php
public function project() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Project', 'id', 'project_id');
}

// Project.php
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

The relationships might be off, I always get the order mixed up but I generally use `php artisan tinker` to make sure that they work.

[Scopes Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes)

[Relationship Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships)

The only other thing I'd suggest is to make sure you have indexes (indices?) on your foreign key columns, e.g. `project_id`, `user_id` and any others, they will help to speed up your queries, especially if your tables are quite large.

Comment: Scope was the Keyword I was missing! Wonderful, I'll read through that but the first paragraph describes exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: no problem, sometimes that one word is all you need to find what you are looking for, glad to help.